# JavaFX - Assign peopleList to peopleTableView

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Given that I am getting I list of items as follows:

```
List<People> peopleList = DbConnection.getPeople();
```

How do I then assign it to my tableView:

```
<TableView fx:id="peopleTableView" layoutY="-7.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="800.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="140.0" text="First Name" fx:id="fName"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="140.0" text="Surname" fx:id="sName"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Gender" fx:id="gender"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Sex" fx:id="sex"/>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

I've tried the following:

```
    DbConnection.connect();
    ObservableList<People> peopleObservableList = DbConnection.getAllPeople();
    FilteredList<People> peopleFilteredList = new FilteredList<>(peopleObservableList, p -> true);
    SortedList<People> sortedList = new SortedList<>(peopleFilteredList);
sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(peopleTableView.comparatorProperty());
    peopleTableView.setItems(sortedList);
```

but get the following error:

*NullPointerException*

Comment: You have to do it inside of a controller connected to that fxml

Comment: How does assignment look? This is what I am struggling to figure out.

Comment: Just fill `TableView.items` with the content of the list. You also need to set appropriate `cellValueFactory`s, if you haven't done this already.